# request.user always returns AnonymousUser - Django

Tags: django

I have an app `authy_me` and wrote a custom URL

```
url(r'^login/$', authy_views.log_me_in, name="login")
```

the `log_me_in` view has the following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as auth_login
def log_me_in(request):

    if request.user.is_staff and not has_2fa(request):
        logger.info('is staff but does not have 2FA, redirecting to Authy account creator')
        return redirect('admin/authy_me/authenticatormodel/')
    elif request.user.is_staff and has_2fa(request):
        logger.info("is staff and 2FA enabled redirecting to Authy verification")
        return redirect('2fa')
    elif not request.user.is_staff and not has_2fa(request):
        logger.info('is not staff and does not have 2FA')

    defaults = {
        'authentication_form': AuthenticationForm,
        'template_name': 'login.html',
    }
    return auth_login(request, **defaults)
```

When I print `request.user` I get it as `AnonymousUser` but the thing is that it was working and I did not change anything! I am not sure what the problem is.

Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate user before passing request to auth_login(),

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

Check, If user is valid user,

```
if not user:
    return False
```

Now, you can pass your request to auth_login()

Hope this helps